# Messed up gitlab permissions and don't know what to do now

Tags: gitlab

I tried to get my gitlab-runner to work and with that I messed up my gitlab configuration really bad...I hope it is possible to restore my self-hosted gitlab instance.

First things first: 
When I run `sudo gitlab-ctl status` I get the output

```
down: alertmanager: 1s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 8770) 1438s
down: prometheus: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 8742) 1438s
```

The rest of it works as it should I guess. As I said before, the problem related in permission denied error because of messing up the configuration with `sudo chown ...`

Is there a way to restore the old user permissions? Or is there a way to get information about the permissions configuration gitlab needs?

Thank you very much!

PS: When I run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` this error appears

```
 ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions ----
    STDOUT: error: could not open /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys
    -rw------- 1 gitlab-redis git 1948 Apr 23 15:33 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys
    STDERR: 
    ---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions ----
    Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions returned 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-shell.rb

     85: execute "#{gitlab_shell_keys_check} check-permissions" do
     86:   user git_user
     87:   group git_group
     88: end
     89: 

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-shell.rb:85:in `from_file'

    execute("/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions") do
      action [:run]
      default_guard_interpreter :execute
      command "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions"
      backup 5
      group "git"
      returns 0
      user "git"
      declared_type :execute
      cookbook_name "gitlab"
      recipe_name "gitlab-shell"
      domain nil
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=13.6.4
    platform=ubuntu
    platform_version=18.04
    ruby=ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
    executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions] (gitlab::gitlab-shell line 85) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions ----
STDOUT: error: could not open /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 gitlab-redis git 1948 Apr 23 15:33 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys
STDERR: 
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions ----
Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions returned 1
```

Comment: `check_permissions` is failling because it cannot even read the `authorized_keys` file. Try this: `chown git.git /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh && chmod 0700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh && chmod 0600 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Make sure that `var/opt/gitlab` can be accessed by the git user (e.g. `x` is set for all users on each directory in the path) and retry `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: Thank you very much, but I get the error /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh: Operation is permitted. Is that the problem you meant with "make sure that ... can be accessed"?

Comment: So I restarted the server and the reconfiguration can be done. But the problem with some down services is still there. 
down: altermanager
down: prometheus
down: postgresql 
And when I access the git url I get the error page 502.

Comment: `gitlab-ctl start <downservice1> <downservice2>` and see what happens

Comment: Some other information I can give you right now: after running `sudo gitlab-ctl tail` I get three logs from these services all saying permissen denied:
` err="opening storage failed: list block dirs in \"/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data\": open /var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data: permission denied"` for example

Comment: After running your commands, it seems like alertmanager and prometheus is working, but after checking with `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` they where down again. I think all of these three services need other permissions, but I don't know which one. I thought the message from above would help.

Comment: Then check permissions on those dirs. Elaborating on what is the content of `...` in `sudo chown ....` would probably help give you more precise suggestion. You can also easily launch the [gitlab docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) and inspect permissions in there as a point of comparison with your current situation.

Comment: The permissions of the directory /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql look like this: `drwx------ 19 gitlab-psql root 4096 Apr 24 12:46 data`
I'm very sorry for my pure suggestions, but I don't know how to describe it better. Can you give me an example what you mean by comparing my configuration with the docker image?

Comment: But if I want to look into the folder data, I can't. I get the `-bash: cd: data/: Permission denied`. With sudo this want work as well, is that the problem? How can I access to this folder right now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using GitLab Omnibus! if so, download the proper version of [update-permissions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/docker/assets/update-permissions) (your GtiLab instance version) and run the script file.
It can fix the permission problems in the case of changing UID/GID and changing ownership/permission of files and directories.

**NOTE: Be careful about using this script. It should be executed with root permission! so read all the file before running and be sure you are using the right version.**

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the permissions problem! But now I get an error related to postgresql. Is it possible to reinstall the software without loosing my repository data? The error says `ERROR:  relation "geo_nodes" does not exist at character 563`

Comment: Your welcome :) it's maybe is due to and upgrade to PostgreSQL  (used PostgreSQL version upgraded recently) and need some migration to be done on the DB. read the GitLab documentation about that upgrade and if it doesn't help, Please ask a new question.

Comment: I think the problem was deleting the postgresql folder within gitlab itself. After updating gitlab to a the newest version, the database was generated again and everything worked well. But my repos where gone. So what I learnded: don't touch software peaces and backup everything right away :)